# Is it possible to open Play Store from application with a predefined search?

Tags: android, android-intent

The following code opens Play store from my android application:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName();
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                    + appPackageName)));
                }
```

Programmatically i want the user to see the search result for all the "File Explorers" available on the Play store as soon as it opens. When i fire the intent, what i see is Picture1 what i want is Picture2. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("market://search?q=File%20Explorers")));
```

"market://" is resolved to the google play store URL and the "search?q=File%20Explorers" will open the search for the given parameters. `%20` is the encoding for a space.